# Django models: default datetime is not translated into SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, timestamp

I am using Django models to create a PostgreSQL-DB. I have a DateTimeField where I would like to set the current timestamp as default value. I am aware of multiple sources suggesting how to do this. However, when I inspect my DB outside of Django, the default timestamp doesn't show up.

Approaches I have tried:

1.

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

2. 

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now
...
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=Now())
```

3. 

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
...
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

What I would expect is for the PostgreSQL database to show:
`TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

What It shows is `timestamp with time zone not null` but no default value. Any ideas on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No this is managed by Django itself.

Comment: Apparently so, but is there a way to add this default value? I am having problems when i add values from another service (not django). For these services there is no default value.

Comment: just manually add this to the database.

Comment: ok but there is no way of doing this through the django models? thanks!

Comment: not as far as I know no, except for making a migration and using `RunSQL`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#runsql the advantage of this is that Django thus will do this with its migration management tool, such that you do not have to manually alter the database(s).

Comment: I prefer Runsql over running a separate script. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, when I inspect my DB outside of Django, the default timestamp doesn't show up.

That is correct, Django itself manages the default values. Not the database, Django also manages the `ON DELETE` trigger, not the database. This gives more flexibility. For example you can pass a callable to the `default` like you did with `default=now`. This callable can perform sophisticated actions to determine the default value like making extra queries, API calls, file I/O, etc. This is not possible with a default at the database side.

You can make a data migration file and manually alter the table. You can initialize a data migration with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

next you can alter the file it has generated and specify a default with:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1 on 2020-12-16 17:14
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', 'migration_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            'ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
        )
    ]
```

The advantage of doing this is that Django manages the migrations, and it will thus migrate the databases that have not been migrated and thus add a default value.